# Pausing a running Jupyter Notebook

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've been running a script in Jupyter Notebook for a few days, it's in the middle of updating data in a dataframe. My WiFi went down, but not cable ethernet and my housemates have to restart the route. Is there any way I can pause the script while conserving the state of the variables? Or maybe export it to csv while the update script is running

Comment: nope :/ depending on whether your dataframe is currently in the notebook's scope, you might be able to interrupt execution and retrieve the current objects in memory. But if the variable is scoped locally to a function or something you're out of luck. Sorry!